# JBOSS Console Logging, recommended in production environment?

Tags: java, logging, jboss

I've looking for an answer on this for a while. In the company I work we have a highly concurrent system but recently found that the logging configuration of the web server (Jboss) includes the Console appender. The application loggers are also going to the console. We started to get deadlocks on the logging actions, most of them to the console appender  (I know that Log4j has a really nasty sincronization bug, but i'm almost sure that we dont have any sincronization method in the related code). Another thing founded, is that the IT Guys regularly access to the console with a putty console, put pauses to check the logs and then just close the putty window.

Is it possible that the console appender, and the use of console for logging and monitoring in a production environment, are causing deadlocks and race conditions on the system?. My understanding is that the console should be used only on development phases with an IDE, because on a highly concurrent system it will be another resource to get (slow because of unbuffered I/O) subject to race conditions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Best practices for Performance tuning JBoss Enterprise Application Platform 5](http://www.jboss.com/pdf/JB_JEAP5_PerformanceTuning_wp_web.pdf), page 9

> Turn off console logging in production
>
> Turn down logging verbosity
>
> Use asynchronous logging.
>
> Wrap debug log statements with If(debugEnabled())

I heavily recommend first and last considerations in production due to a bug in Log4J that calculates what to log before logging it i.e. if `MyClass#toString()` is a heavy operation, Log4J will first calculate this `String` before (yes, it will do the heavy operation) and then it will check if this `String` must be logged (pretty bad, indeed =).

Also, tell the IT guys to use the `less` command when checking the log files in order to not blocking the files, do not check the console directly =. This command works in Linux, if your server is on Unix environment, the command will be `tail` (based on @Toni's comment).

---

IMO, I think that an official JBoss performance guide is the best proof to stop using the console logging in production (even if this still doesn't prove your deadlock problem).

Comment: Hi, thx for your answer. I've already taken in account that document, but i need to prove some way that using the console in production could cause a dead lock situation. The debug mode is on, so is a pretty heavy logging on console. Thanks again, the less command will be really useful!

Comment: If you're in an UNIX environment, a part from the less command, we use the "tail" command: e.g. "tail -f server.log", it shows constantly the new changes produced in a file.

Comment: The tail command is also included in all the major Linux distributions. :-) It's used to show the last part of a file (and with the -f option it's used to output the new data as the file grows).